# Exception accessing Google Cloud Storage from newly created Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I have a working nodejs application on an older google compute engine. After migration the application to a new compute engine I get on this line:

```
const [files] = await storage.bucket(GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID_PUBLIC).getFiles();
```

the following exception:

```
Error: Could not refresh access token: A Not Found error was returned while attempting to retrieve an accesstoken for the Compute Engine built-in service account. This may be because the Compute Engine instance does not have any permission scopes specified: Could not refresh access token: 
at Gaxios._request (/smar/backend.smar.shop/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:129:23)                                                                                                                                                                                       
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
at async metadataAccessor (/smar/backend.smar.shop/node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/index.js:68:21)                                                                                                                                                                            
at async Compute.refreshTokenNoCache (/smar/backend.smar.shop/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/computeclient.js:53:20)                                                                                                                                             
at async Compute.getRequestMetadataAsync (/smar/backend.smar.shop/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:261:17)                                                                                                                                         
at async Compute.getRequestHeaders (/smar/backend.smar.shop/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:238:26)                                                                                                                                               
at async GoogleAuth.authorizeRequest (/smar/backend.smar.shop/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:600:25)                                                                                                                                               
at async Promise.all (index 1)
```

I guess the important part here is: **because the Compute Engine instance does not have any permission scopes specified**

Can someone please explain me what this means or where I can find those permission scopes? Do I have to modify the configuration of the Compute Engine?

Comment: To edit scope, Menu>compute engine>VM instances> name > stop instance > edit > cloud API scopes.

Comment: @danyL I feel somehow dumb. I have stopped the instance. But in the edit mode I can not see anything with scopes: https://www.screencast.com/t/pmUqCJ6b do I miss a permission?

Comment: after edit go to access scopes just above SAVE button > set access for each API

Comment: @danyL I love you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` alias `cloud-platform` is the least required for the VM. Likely the other one instance may use a different service account with different roles and/or different API access scopes?

See "[Register your application for Google Cloud Storage JSON API in Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=storage-api.googleapis.com)"; that's at least what the NodeJS client [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/#using-the-client-library) suggests. Also see:

- [Setting up a new instance to run as a service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#using)
- [Changing the service account and access scopes for an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes)
- [IAM permissions for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions)